# Скругление блоков через css

Tags: html, css, css3, вёрстка

Как можно скруглить блоки средствами css чтобы получить примерно такой результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал использовать `border-radius: 0 0 50% 50%;`, но ничего не выходит, слишком большой радиус скругления. Есть идеи, может кто сталкивался?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь таким приемом:

```
border-radius: 0 0 50% 50% / 0 0 40px 40px;
```

До слеша задаются горизонтальные радиусы, после слеша - вертикальные. Можно задавать через shorthand-свойство `border-radius`, можно в отдельных свойствах:

```
border-top-left-radius: 0;
border-top-right-radius: 0;
border-bottom-right-radius: 50% 40px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 50% 40px;
```

[Подробнее о приеме (англ.)](https://www.sitepoint.com/setting-css3-border-radius-with-slash-syntax/)

```css
.section {
  background: #FBF3E6;
  border-radius: 0 0 50% 50% / 0 0 40px 40px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: -40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.section_orange {
  background: #FFC100;
  z-index: 2;
}

.section_pink {
  background: #FE7A7C;
  z-index: 1;
}

.section_green {
  background: #02F55E;
}
```

```html
<div class="section section_orange"></div>
<div class="section section_pink"></div>
<div class="section section_green"></div>
```

[Или посмотреть на jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gambala/dwoa2ruh/)

Comment: Это не подойдет, необходимо чтобы скругление плавно переходило к центру блока а не только по углам. Поэтому свойство border-radius не подходит вовсе.

Comment: Не понял вас, почему не подойдет? Пример соответствует вашему скриншоту.

Comment: Смотрю действительно все так как в примере, но не понимаю как это работает. По отдельности эти параметры абсолютно не так работают а через слэш происходит какая то магия, пожалуйста объясните подробнее или где об этом можно почитать?

Comment: Вертикальные и горизонтальные радиусы, дополнил ответ, с ссылкой на статью по теме.

Comment: Спасибо, вы очень сильно помогли.